# Can I get onPreviewFrame under specifc shutter-value in Android?

Tags: android

I want to obtain continuous preview frames under specific shutter-value in Android.

I set the wanted ISO, and start the camera, I find only images using takePicture() are really changed (since I want continuous frames, so such mode cannot satisfy my requirement), but images in onPreviewFrame() are not changed at all. Some codes are as follows:

```
    parameters.set("shutter-value", "125");     
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(pre);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Share your code where you taking a picture ?

Comment: I use a button to capture the preview picture. 
        
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(pre);
                }
            }
        );

Answer (score 0):

Just an update.

I found iphone (from IOS 8) can adjust shutter speed and iso in preview and recording mode.

https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/
http://iphonephotographyschool.com/ios-8-manual-camera-controls/